# Can I allow opening windows from everywhere in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following situations where I would like to display some widgets.

My main windows is mostly a text editor.
I have an action called 'Run', which interprets the text and does something.
One of the possible results is that a window needs to be opened.
It works, but the window is only displayed after the `run` function (which I have as a slot)returns.

Another situation I have to open a window is that I want to be abe to same interpreter to run from console input.
But opening the window in this case results in errors like:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

(Parent is Oxygen::WidgetStateEngine(0xee2d90), parent's thread is QThread(0xda53b0), current thread is QThread(0x7f2178004000)

QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
```

What can I do to somehow 'centralize' window operations so that this does not happen ?

Comment: ***What can I do to somehow 'centralize' window operations so that this does not happen ?*** Create the window from the main/GUI thread. Use signals and slots to send a signal from the worker threads back to the GUI thread.

Comment: How do I get a pointer to that window back in the worker thread ?

Comment: In the slot that creates the QWidget use QObject::sender to get a pointer to the object that emitted the signal back to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

All GUI objects are to be created within your main thread. You can get access to `QMainWindow` instance from any place in your code using static method [QApplication::topLevelWidgets()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets)